# How to create list of buttons in scrollview based on JSON http response?

Tags: android, json, android-activity, scrollview, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I was thinking how to dynamically render N buttons in relative layout that were fetched via http request as JSON response (JSONObject), for the sake of simplicity let's say that all we got in JSON is

1. A name of the button (the label)
2. A text that will show in alert dialog after button click

Let's bet that the JSON we got from http response looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "label":"Button 1",
      "alert":"Button 1 has been clicked"
   },
   {
      "label":"Button 2",
      "alert":"Button 2 has been clicked"
   },
   {
      "label":"Button 3",
      "alert":"Button 3 has been clicked"
   }
]
```

So it should render something like this:

```
|  Button 1 | // onclick the alert dialog shows "Button 1 has been clicked"
-------------
| Button 2 | // onclick the alert dialog shows "Button 2 has been clicked"
------------
| Button 3 | // onclick the alert dialog shows "Button 3 has been clicked"
```

All I need is to know how to create dynamic UI elements (not predefined in layout XML file) that can be after assimilated with additional code, like onClick

Comment: May we see what you have tried to resolve this,  Bartłomiej?

Comment: I used ListView, but I am now learning how to make is customized

Comment: OK, would you add what you tried to the question? It is good to get into that habit to show that you've done solid research on the problem. You received two answers below too - how did you get on with them? Are you able to reply (comment, vote, accept) on any of them?

Comment: I will do it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2):

First take a size of your parsed `JSONArray` and loop it through

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  

        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length; j++ {
            Button btnTag = new Button(this);
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String label= jsonObject.getString("label");
            btnTag.setText(""+ label);
            btnTag.setId(j +1);
            row.addView(btnTag);
        }

        layout.addView(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the code, but this what you should do:

1. Instead of creating list of buttons. Create a RecyclerView with a button (or whatever layout you want in one row) as the RecyclerView element.
2. Create a Recycler view adapter which accepts the List of POJO of the json object and inflate the RecyclerView element layout.
3. To get the POJO you can use GSON. Google it.
4. Now in the adapter use the "label" to set the button's title and use "alert" to set the toast message field that you're going to display.